# How to discover associated model attributes from each result in Sphinx result set? (Rails, ThinkingSphinx)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have the following Rails models:

```
ad
category

ad belongs to category
```

When I perform a search for an advert only the adverts title is searched for a match, I want to be able to find out how many ads in the result set belong to each category so that I can then generate a list of category names showing how many matching ads there are in each.

I have no idea how to extract the category names & number of ads within each category from the sphinx result set, can you help?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for getting a summary of the number of ads per category would be to add an attribute of the category_id to your Ad index definition, and flag it as a facet as well.

```
has category_id, :facet => true
```

Then, after running `rake ts:rebuild` so Sphinx is aware of your changes, run a facet search:

```
Ad.facets[:category_id] # => {1 => 10, 2 => 4}
```

The extra step that you'll need to do yourself is to translate each category id (the keys of the resulting hash) into a Category model/name.